# Erro ao Incluir uma Image no app

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

Criei um projeto padrão, inclui umas imagens .png no projeto na pasta principal:

Projeto
 - image.png
 - index.android.js
 - .....

Ao executar o run-android é apresentado um erro que indica que a imagem não foi localizada:

> "error: bundling failed: "Unable to resolve module `logoimg.png` from
>   `C:\\Users\\Ayala\\Documents\\Developer\\React\\BrunoDantas\\index.android.js`:
>   Module does not exist in the module map\n\nThis might be related to
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try
>   the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman
>   watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf
>   node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr
>   $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`."

Alguém já passou por esse problema?

Comment: Você pode mostrar o código em que tentou inserir a imagem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente isto:

```
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Resumindo o caminho para a imagem esta errado. Na pergunta voce diz que o nome da imagem é `image.png` mas no log esta `logoimg.png` então já tem alguma coisa errada ai.

Na React as imagens (modulos tambem) tem o caminho relativo se o seu `index.android.js` e o `logoimg.png` estão no mesmo nivel o ficaria algo como:

```
<Image source={require('./logoimg.png')}/>
```